# Double forward slash period in regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I've recently started using regular expressions in Java and I ran into a strange expression.

The problem asks to find "words" consisting of only letters and at most one concluding period.
So for example, if I input the string:

```
one two. wr7ng not1 three. nope..
```

The engine will find one, two and three as the matching words. The given solution for the problem is this Pattern:

```
for (String tok : s.split(" ")) {
  if (tok.matches("[a-zA-Z]+//.?")) {
    // code done to record successful match
  }
}
```

What do the two forward slashes mean? I compared this expression with this one:

```
[a-zA-Z]+.?
```

And found only the latter incorrectly accepted digits in the final slot (the period). Is this the only difference?

Comment: Maybe it's a typo and they are supposed to be backslashes. Forward slash to my knowledge is not a special character in regex, but the `.` is and to use it like a regular `.` you have to escape it.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure it wasn't *backslashes*?

```
  "[a-zA-Z]+\\.?"
```

Two backslashes in a literal string is interpreted to mean, "insert a single backslash in the literal string".  (As a convention, in many languages, backslash anychar means, "insert anychar").

When the literal string is interpreted as a regular expression,
the actual text

```
         \.
```

means, "match the 'period' as a literal character".

If you don't have the backslash "escape character", the  in most Regexp engines means, "match any character".

Comment: Okay, great I understand what you are saying. Thanks for clearing this up!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have a typo there.  It should be `"[a-zA-Z]+\\."`.

That string value becomes the regular expression value `[a-zA-Z]+\.`.  The backslash indicates that the `.` should be treated as a literal period.  Without it, `.` is a special regular-expression metacharacter that matches *any* single character (including digits).

Answer (score 4):

The exact RE is:

```
[a-zA-Z]+\.?
```

and to compile it using Java, you need one more back slash \ which means an escape character in a Java string:

```
"[a-zA-Z]+\\.?"
```

Answer (score 1):

A forward slash has no special meaning in a regex, so "//" means match two forward slashes.

If that doesn't make sense, this is either a typo, or you've misread or mis-transcribed the regex.  The obvious "correction" of replacing forward slashes with back slashes gives this:

```
    tok.matches("[a-zA-Z]+\\.?")
```

which means "match roman letters followed by an optional `'.'`".  In context, that *could* mean an English word followed by a fullstop / period.

---

For the record, `"[a-zA-Z]+.?"` matches 1 or more roman letters followed (optionally) by one more character.  The "eagerness" of the `+` operator means that the optional character will be a non-letter ... if anything.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `.` (dot) will be interpreted as a regex metacharacter which means "any character".

Using `\.` will give a compiler error viz. Illegal Escape Character

Using `\\.` will be interpreted as a simple `.` (dot) character, which is what you need to use.

So for a word that contains only letters you use `[a-zA-Z]+` where the `+` (plus) is a quantifier which means "one or more".

For a single `.` (dot) character you use `\\.`.
Now for "atmost once" part of your `.` (dot) character you will use the `?` quantifier which means "one or more". Your expression for the `.` part becomes `\\.?`.

Hence your regex expression will be `[a-zA-Z]+\\.?`.